# Does PHP have like ruby gem bundler?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, bundler, gem-bundler

I am PHP programmer that know Rails.

Ruby [gem bundler](http://gembundler.com/) very good tool to install dependencies, does php have something like that?(maybe some php framework have such tool).

Expanation about gem bundler:

> Bundler manages an application's dependencies through its entire life across many machines systematically and repeatably.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/).

> Composer is a package manager tracking local dependencies of your projects and libraries.

Then you have [Packagist](http://packagist.org/) (which is the main Composer repository).

> Packagist is the main Composer repository. It aggregates all sorts of PHP packages that are installable with Composer.

And you can also manage your private/own repository using [Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis).

> Simple static Composer repository generator.

By the way, a post from the author about [*What & Why Composer*](http://nelm.io/blog/2011/12/composer-part-1-what-why/).

Comment: cool thanks, have few questions: 1. what difference between composer and ruby gem bundler?  Does some php framework use this, if not do you know why?(i use zend, yii - they dont use it)

Comment: I don't realy know Gem bundler. Symfony use it (it was mainly launched from Symfony community). Zend use it [since 2.0](http://packages.zendframework.com/#composer). About Yii there seems to have a [dead discussion about it](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26631-composer-support/) (don't know the state).

Answer (score 0):

there is [pecl](http://pecl.php.net/) for php, for php extensions.